# Reading in a SQL file and Using Count Vectorizer to get word occurences

Tags: python, pandas

I wanto to read a `SQL` file and use `CountVectorizer` to get word occurences.

I have the following code so far:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer




df = pd.read_sql(q, dlconn)
print(df)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts= count_vect.fit_transform(df)

print(X_train_counts.shape)
print(count_vect.vocabulary_)
```

This gives an output of `'cat': 1, 'dog': 0`

It seems that it is taking just the name of the column `animal` and counting from there.

How do I get it to access the full column and get a chart that shows every word in the column and its frequency?

Comment: Is the output of `print(df)` correct? What does `df` contain at that point?

Comment: what about df.values which is the numpy matrix of the dataframe values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the `CountVectorizer` docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform), the method `fit_transform()` expects an iterable of strings.
It cannot handle a `DataFrame` directly.

But iterating over a dataframe returns the labels of the columns, not the values. I suggest you try [`df.itertuples()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas-dataframe-itertuples) instead.

Try something like this:

```
value_list = [
    row[0]
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)]
print(value_list)
print(type(value_list))
print(type(value_list[0]))

X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(value_list)
```

Each value in `value_list` should be of type `str`.
Let us know if that helps.

---

Here is a little example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['my big dog', 'my lazy cat'])
>>> df
             0
0   my big dog
1  my lazy cat

>>> value_list = [row[0] for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)]
>>> value_list
['my big dog', 'my lazy cat']

>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> cv = CountVectorizer()
>>> x_train = cv.fit_transform(value_list)
>>> x_train
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> x_train.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
>>> cv.vocabulary_
{'my': 4, 'big': 0, 'dog': 2, 'lazy': 3, 'cat': 1}
```

And now you can display the word count of each row (each input string separately):

```
>>> for word, col in cv.vocabulary_.items():
...     for row in range(x_train.shape[0]):
...         print('word:{:10s} | row:{:2d} | count:{:2d}'.format(word, row, x_train[row,col]))
word:my         | row: 0 | count: 1
word:my         | row: 1 | count: 1
word:big        | row: 0 | count: 1
word:big        | row: 1 | count: 0
word:dog        | row: 0 | count: 1
word:dog        | row: 1 | count: 0
word:lazy       | row: 0 | count: 0
word:lazy       | row: 1 | count: 1
word:cat        | row: 0 | count: 0
word:cat        | row: 1 | count: 1
```

You can also display the total word count (sum of rows):

```
>>> x_train_sum = x_train.sum(axis=0)
>>> x_train_sum
    matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)
>>> for word, col in cv.vocabulary_.items():
...     print('word:{:10s} | count:{:2d}'.format(word, x_train_sum[0, col]))
word:my         | count: 2
word:big        | count: 1
word:dog        | count: 1
word:lazy       | count: 1
word:cat        | count: 1

>>> with open('my-file.csv', 'w') as f:
...     for word, col in cv.vocabulary_.items():
...         f.write('{};{}\n'.format(word, x_train_sum[0, col]))
```

This should clarify how you can use the tools you have.

Comment: Hey Ralf, this got me to an output like this:                                                        
(0,1849) 2                                                                                                                                                        (0,1798) 2                                                                                                               
etc                                                                                                                                     How do I get the actual word to come out with its frequency next to it?

Comment: What line of the code exactly gives you that output? Do you get any errors with this?

Comment: print(X_train_counts). Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: `X_train_counts` is a so-called document-term matrix; it shows which word (the different columns) apears how many times in the input strings (the rows). You have to look inside the `count_vect.vocabulary_` to discover which word each of the columns refers to.

Comment: is there not a way to get the ouput of the word with the frequency next to it though? When I print count_vect.vocabulary_  I get an associated number with the word but its just the order of the words in alphabetical order.

Comment: I think the number is the position of the word in `X_train_counts`.

Comment: You can corroborate that with a small test with only a few words and see if it really is that way

Comment: I believe that is true. But can I get it so that it is: word: 'ok', frequency 2

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you very much. Last thing I need is to just export this to a csv file with the two columns: one for word, other for frequency. Any chance you can help with that?

Comment: Having trouble finding a way to get the output of the loop into a variable or data frame. and then trying to convert that into a csv. any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: @forthewin I added file export to my answer.

Comment: this gives me a single column with the string of word and frequency in the same cell. if possible, can we get a single column for word and another column for frequency?

Comment: @forthewin that depends on the separator you use; as you can see, I use the semicolon (`;`) but you can also use a comma (`,`) in the line `f.write(...)`

Comment: and when opening the file, you usually can choose which character will be the column separator

Comment: Hey Ralf, I'm trying to eliminate stop words without using nltk. Is there a way to do this only using scikit? and then plotting using matplot lib

Comment: I'm not familiar with nltk, so I don't know. But please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you have doubst or problems that are different from this question.